# Hpricot parse image alt text

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I am trying to pull out the alt text from all images on a page using Hpricot but can't figure out how to do it.

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: It's real easy to do, but we'd like to see what you've tried since it is so easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first time using [Hpricot](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot) so be gentle.  I think this isolates the data you were asking about.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'hpricot'

page = "<html><body><p>Create a link of an image:<a href=\"default.asp\"><img src=\"smiley.gif\" alt=\"alt_text_1\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" /></a></p><p>No border around the image, but still a link:<a href=\"default.asp\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"smiley.gif\" alt=\"alt_text_2\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" /></a></p></body></html>"
doc = Hpricot(page)

doc.search("//img").each do |img|
    puts img.attributes['alt']
end
```

Output looks like this:

```
#=> alt_text_1
#=> alt_text_2
```